# taking a date in restfull api param or body?

Tags: spring, rest, api, optimization

Im having a doubt.
I have a **get request** and i have to take a **Date** in a **RESTful api** 
which of this two is the best practice?

1. taking the date as long in the request parameter
2. adding a request body and taking it as Date

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Using message body for GET requests is not recommended. You can look at [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/12443348).
So using request parameters is more preferable.